# "Sack" data structure in C#

Tags: c#

The idea is to have a data structure that holds any number of objects of any type. Objects can be retrieved, or removed permanently, at random. Also, it can be cleared (or emptied).

This class just provides the ability to select a random object from a collection, with the option of removing it.

```
public class Sack
{
    private List<object> objects;

    public Sack()
    {
        objects = new List<object>();
    }

    public void Add<T>(T obj)
    {
        objects.Add(obj);
    }

    public object Retrieve()
    {
        int numberObjects = objects.Count;

        Random rand = new Random();
        int selectedIndex = rand.Next(0, numberObjects);

        return objects[selectedIndex];
    }

    public object Remove()
    {
        int numberObjects = objects.Count;

        Random rand = new Random();
        int selectedIndex = rand.Next(0, numberObjects);

        object selectedObject = objects[selectedIndex];
        objects.RemoveAt(selectedIndex);

        return selectedObject;
    }

    public void Empty()
    {
        objects.Clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. I didn't DV, but you also got a close vote "Needs details or clarity". In its current form your question lacks context about why you created this class (what do you want to do with it)  and how should it be used.

Comment: Thank you. I will add some more detail to the question.

Comment: @Al2110 Does that code work as intended?

Comment: Yes. Are there any improvements that can be made to the code, based on the specifications? In terms of readability, variable naming, etc.

Comment: Just for future reference, the statement `There are no concrete uses for this class`. could make this question off-topic. We are looking for real code that does something and generally an explanation of  what the code does.

Comment: @pacmaninbw really? Well, this code certainly does something, and he does describe what it does. It may not be the most useful structure in the world, but I'd say it's a nice exercise...

Comment: @Quintec could be useful for property-based testing, or a card game, or any number of things. My only quibble is that it's harder to provide meaningful advice divorced from context

Comment: Use ConcurrentBag instead if you need thread safety. See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentbag-1

Comment: I'm not a fan of the methods `Remove()` and `Retrieve()` being so similar, spelled so similarly, and having significantly different operation. It seems ripe for confusion. I'd rather see something like `Retrieve()` and `RetrieveDiscard()`, or `Peek()` and `Remove()`.

Comment: @BaconBits If you have an actual sack with items in it, and retrieve one of them, the item is removed from the sack in the process. Personally I would expect a "sack" data structure to behave the same way if it had a "retrieve" method.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist I'm not sure what your point is. The `Retrieve()` method *doesn't* remove the item from the sack.  If you're trying to disagree with me, then you've mistakenly proven my point that the method names are poor by making the very mistake I described.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go and encourage you to use `Generics` instead of `object`. When you use `object` you're adding a casting operations in the back-scene, which means you might have a chance of getting casting exceptions at run-time. So, using generics would avoid that, and it would perform faster.

Also, in your code, you're using `List`, which is fine, but why you don't benefit from the existed interfaces such as `ICollection`, `IList` ..etc. These would give you many advantages, for instance, use `ICollection` such as `Sack<T> : ICollection<T>` you'll be able to use `foreach` loop (because it implements `IEnumerable` interfaces). So, make use of .NET existing interfaces, and don't take the long road.

Also, You can create an interface say `ISack<T> : ICollection<T>` add the additional methods that you want, then do `Sack<T> : ISack<T>`

for your random index, you can declare the `Random` and `SelectedIndex` at the class level, and then create a method that returns a random index.

example :

```
public class Sack<T>
{

    private readonly IList<T> objects = new List<T>();

    private readonly Random rand = new Random();

    private int SelectedIndex = -1;


    public T Retrieve()
    {
        RandomIndex();
        return objects[SelectedIndex];
    }

    public T Remove()
    {
        RandomIndex();
        var removedObject = objects[SelectedIndex];
        objects.Remove(removedObject);
        return removedObject;

    }

    private void RandomIndex()
    {
        // keep creating a new random index until you get a non-null object. 
        // [ToDo] : what if object.Count == 0 ? how should you handle it ? 
        while (true)
        {
            if ((SelectedIndex == -1 || objects[SelectedIndex] == null))
            {
                SelectedIndex = rand.Next(0, objects.Count);
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I have added `ICollection<T>` to the class, which would give you more options and customization

```
 public class Sack<T> : ICollection<T>
    {
        private readonly IList<T> objects = new List<T>();

        private readonly Random rand = new Random();

        private int SelectedIndex = -1;

        public T this[int index]
        {
            get => this[index];
            set => this[index] = value;

        }
        public int Count => objects.Count;

        public bool IsReadOnly => objects.IsReadOnly;

        public void Add(T item)
        {
            objects.Add(item);
        }

        public void Clear() => objects.Clear();

        public bool Contains(T item) => objects.Contains(item);

        public void CopyTo(T[] array, int index) => objects.CopyTo(array, index);

        public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() => objects.GetEnumerator();

        public int IndexOf(T item) => objects.IndexOf(item);

        public void Insert(int index, T item) => objects.Insert(index, item);

        public bool Remove(T item) => objects.Remove(item);

        public void RemoveAt(int index) => objects.RemoveAt(index);

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => objects.GetEnumerator();

        public T Retrieve()
        {
            RandomIndex();
            return objects[SelectedIndex];
        }

        public T Remove()
        {
            RandomIndex();
            var removedObject = objects[SelectedIndex];
            objects.Remove(removedObject);
            return removedObject;

        }

        private void RandomIndex()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                if ((SelectedIndex == -1 || objects[SelectedIndex] == null))
                {
                    SelectedIndex = rand.Next(0, objects.Count);
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }

            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Since the objects in the sack are unordered, it doesn't make sense to implement `IndexOf` for it. Making the sack an `IEnumerable` sounds fine to me, but `ICollection` is simply wrong.

Comment: @RolandIllig, as long as OP is using `objects.Add(item)` as is, it's sorted Collection, so I thought the OP only needs to (Retrieve and Remove) at random index. If OP really needs to put the objects in unordered indexes, then `HashTable` would be more appropriate on that matter.

Comment: The "sorted Collection" is only an implementation detail, and the important point is _not_ that it is ordered but that it allows fast access by index. Exactly for this reason, `HashTable` would not make sense.

Comment: @RolandIllig maybe I was't clear enough, if  I just did `objects.Add(..)` then do objects[object.Count] I'll get the last inserted element. meaning, It's still sorted list, I should do some resorting or shuffle the elements inside the list to a different order so when I do `objects.Add(..)` then `objects[object.Count] ` I should get a total different element than the one I just added.

Comment: @iSR5 I wouldn't shuffle the list internally just because the collection isn't ordered. If the collection isn't ordered, it just doesn't make sense to index it, so don't provide that functionality. Also note that `objects[object.Count]` will throw an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.

Comment: Just because you use a `List` internally, doesn't mean that you automatically should implement `IList`. This class is unordered, so it doesn't make sense to implement `IList`.

Comment: @iSR5 "as long as OP is using objects.Add(item) as is, it's sorted Collection". A stable (not sorted, but I guess that's what you meant) collection is called a list (that's the one defining difference between the two interfaces). ICollection elements do not have a stable position, that's why it doesn't have things like IndexOf or indexers or options to insert elements at specific positions.

Comment: As I understand the question, OP wants to put objects of different types in the same Sack. So using Generics the way this answer does, goes against the specs.

Answer (score 19):

- You don't use any method which is specific to `List<T>`. You should always code against interfaces if possible, meaning you should use `IList<T>` instead of `List<T>`.
- If `Retrieved` is called very often in a short time it is likely that you get the same `object` each time. This is because `Random` when [instantiated](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random?view=netframework-4.8#instantiating-the-random-number-generator) will use the system clock to provide a seed value. You should have one `Random` object as a class-level field which should be instantiated in the constructor or directly.
- The genericness of the method `Add<T>` doesn't buy you anything. A simple `Add(object)` would be enough and does the exact same.
- `objects` should be made `readonly` because you don't change it.
- For `Retrieve` and `Remove` I wouldn't introduce the `numberObjects` variable but if you want to keep it you should rename it to e.g `numberOfObjects`.

Implementing the mentioned points would look like this:

```
public class Sack
{
    private readonly IList<object> objects = new List<object>();
    private readonly Random rand = new Random();

    public void Add(object obj)
    {
        objects.Add(obj);
    }

    public object Retrieve()
    {
        int selectedIndex = rand.Next(0, objects.Count);

        return objects[selectedIndex];
    }

    public object Remove()
    {
        int selectedIndex = rand.Next(0, objects.Count);

        object selectedObject = objects[selectedIndex];
        objects.RemoveAt(selectedIndex);

        return selectedObject;
    }

    public void Empty()
    {
        objects.Clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: What if I want to provide the option of emptying the contents to a specific collection, rather than just clearing it? Provide an overload for `Empty()` so that the data structure can be passed into it?

Comment: I would use an overloaded method which takes a `Type` and then I would remove all objects of this `Type`.

Comment: It seems a `Count` property would be in order as well - most collections-esque tend to have it

Comment: If `objects` is private, readonly and cannot be injected into `Sack`, there's no benefit to be had by coding against `IList<T>` rather than `List<T>`.

Comment: Worth noting that the comment about instances of Random created close together using the same seed only applies to .Net Framework. .Net Core uses a dedicated RNG instance to seed each new Random() instance, so the seed will be different. [Source Code](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/Random.cs,9c7dc70094b06e3d), [Stack Overflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57631207/6617427)

Answer (score 7):

### Testing your code

To make your code testable, you should allow the code that uses this `Sack` to supply a custom random number generator.

In your unit test for the `Sack` class, you should create a custom `TestingRandom` class that derives from `Random` and overrides the `Next(int, int)` method. In your TestingRandom class you should ensure that the amount of requested randomness is exactly what you expect.

Given a set of 5 things, when you take them all out of the `Sack`, your random number generator must have generated randomness `5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1`. Not more, not less. This ensures that the distribution of objects returned by the `Sack` *can* be fair. It doesn't guarantee that, but it detects mistakes quickly.

### Performance

Do you use this class to manage millions of objects? Because if you do, the `RemoveAt` call will make it very slow as that method needs to copy half of the array on average.

To improve performance, you can change the code so that it always removes the element at the end:

```
var index = RandomIndex();
var obj = objects[index];
objects[index] = objects[objects.Count - 1];
objects.RemoveAt(objects.Count - 1);
return obj;
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the `Retrieve` and the `Remove` methods share much of the same code, and since `Remove` also retrieves, I would suggest merging the 2.  Adding a default argument and a conditional, to the `Retrieve` method, would do the trick:

```
public object Retrieve(bool remove = false)
{
    int selectedIndex = rand.Next(0, objects.Count);
    object selectedObject = objects[selectedIndex];
    if(remove)
    {
        objects.RemoveAt(selectedIndex);
    {
    return selectedObject;
}
```

Comment: While I agree that removing redundancy is a good thing, this is not the way, I would choose. Having one method behaving two very different operations based on a bool parameters, makes the API very unintuitive to use.

Answer (score 1):

I'd inherit from List to avoid proxying functions like Clear() with no value-add, or write an *extension method* over List for the randomized retrieval.

```
public static class RandomRemover
{
    private static readonly Random rand = new Random();

    public static object Retrieve(this List<object> target)
    {
        int selectedIndex = rand.Next(0, target.Count);
        return target[selectedIndex];
    }
}
```

cf. [open/closed principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open%E2%80%93closed_principle)

Answer (score 0):

`Retrieve` and `Remove` both share this piece of code:

```
int numberObjects = objects.Count;

Random rand = new Random();
int selectedIndex = rand.Next(0, numberObjects);
```

I would recommend refactoring it into a private helper:

```
int GetRandomIndex()
{
    int numberObjects = objects.Count;

    Random rand = new Random();
    int selectedIndex = rand.Next(0, numberObjects);
}
```

And then just call it like this:

```
public object Retrieve()
{
    int selectedIndex = GetRandomIndex();

    return objects[selectedIndex];
}
```